# Simple unbiased mean estimator for censored data

Tags: bayesian, mean, censoring, frequentist

Suppose I have an i.i.d. random sample of size $n$ s.t. $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for all $i$. But suppose my observed sample is left censored, such that any $x_i$ observation is replaced with some constant value $U$ for all $x_i \leq U$. So $X_i$ is left-censored at $U$. I am interesting in estimating $\bar{x}$, the sample mean of the $x_i$.

I followed the [Stan user manual](https://mc-stan.org/docs/stan-users-guide/censored-data.html) to estimate the mean of a sample like this by treating the observed values as data, and the censored values as parameters to be estimated. The Stan code that I wrote was able to correctly estimate the mean with a reasonable amount of precision. But unfortunately this kind of Bayesian estimator with Stan is kind of cumbersome to use and implement. **Is there a frequentist/MLE way to estimate the mean? I would want such an estimator to be unbiased and consistent.** I'm specifically talking about the left-censored case, but I guess an MLE estimator for the right- or interval-censored case would be similar.

Comment: Consistent is easy; unbiased not so much.  One *ad hoc* method I have used, with some trepidation -- it was necessary to be consistent with the OLS estimator in cases where no censoring actually occurs -- is to use the MLE for the mean but adjust the MLE estimate of the error variance by a factor of $(n-p-1)/n$ for the purpose of computing confidence and prediction limits. There's also an interesting issue here: would it suffice just to be unbiased, or should it be *unbiased conditional on the number of censored values?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of censored data, I would strongly suggest not caring about the mean so much but rather consider quantiles, i.e. the survival function if this ok in terms of the research question being asked. Outliers can have a strong influence on the mean *and* are more likely to be censored. So if your normal assumption is incorrect, you can add a lot of bias to the estimate of the mean. For example, if you assume your data is normal, but it's really a t-distribution, the left censoring will introduce a right-side bias to your estimate because on average, you'll assume your left censored values are higher than the really are.

However, estimators like the Kaplan Meier estimator will be a consistent estimator for the median and other quantiles. As long as your outcome is independent of your censoring mechanism, this will be consistent and as long as the censoring isn't too extreme, the estimate of the median should be minimal bias.

In your case of a constant left censoring at $U$, this will be dependent on whether  $U < \mu$, in which case you case you can just use the the median directly, ignoring censoring. You can estimate whether $U < \mu$ by simply checking if less than half the values are censored. On the other hand, if you have constant censoring and more than half of your data is censored, you don't really have any hope of getting a reliable estimate of the median (or mean!) without extremely strong assumptions of the distribution which you can't really check!

To circle back to your question, if you still want to estimate the mean and if you are willing to make the strong assumption that your data is normal, the median will be equal to the mean, so you can just use your standard estimator of the median given above. But this is leaning for on assumptions than I would be comfortable with.

**EDIT:**
In the comments, there was discussion of using the "redistribute to the right" (or left in this case) method. Reading up about this, redistributing to the right will result in the Kaplan Meier curves (see background [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3339805/#R4)). Unfortunately, the Kaplan Meier curves can lead to heavily biased estimates of the mean! As a simulation, see this R code:

```
library(survival)

# Simulating right censored data
sim_surv_data = function(n = 100){
  t_time = rexp(n)
  c_time = rexp(n)
  is_observed = t_time < c_time
  y = c_time
  y[is_observed] = t_time[is_observed]
  ans = data.frame(y = y, obs = is_observed)
  return(ans) 
}

# Compute mean from KM curve
km_to_mean = function(km_fit){
  sum_obj = summary(km_fit)
  times = sum_obj$time
  # Convert survival function to PMF
  surv = sum_obj$surv
  shifted_survs = c(1, head(surv, length(surv) - 1))
  pmf = shifted_survs - surv 
  ans = sum(pmf * times)
  return(ans)
}

sim_once = function(n = 100){
  df = sim_surv_data(n)
  km_fit = survfit(Surv(df$y, event=df$obs, type='right')~1)
  ans = km_to_mean(km_fit)
  return(ans)
}

res = NULL 
for(i in 1:400){
  res[i] = sim_once()
}

estimated_mean = round(mean(res), 3)
se = round(sd(res) / sqrt(length(res) - 1), 3)
msg = "Estimated Mean From KM Curve\n True mean = 1"
msg = paste0(msg, "\nEstimate = ", estimated_mean, " SE = ", se)
hist(res, 
     main = msg, 
     xlab = "Estimated Mean")
```

This results in the following:
[image: histogram of means]

Comment: If not all observations are subject to censoring and you have a decent number of unccensored observations you can use multiple imputation to derive a more distribution-free estimate of the mean.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I think that approach will be flawed. If you use a parametric distribution to impute the censored values, you're circling back to the potential bias of using a parametric distribution. If you impute from the KM curves, you will have a big issue of properly sampling from the tails (since it's a step function) which will likely lead to much more bias than just using an incorrect parametric distribution.

Comment: I should have clarified.  Use predictive mean matching or redistribution to the left/right, not parametric imputation.  This imputation doesn't use KM.

Comment: @FrankHarrell but this won't work due to the censoring of extreme values?

Comment: Under the condition I mentioned it can work.  For example if you have observations left censored at 100 but you also have some complete observations that are < 100.  You take a random sample of the complete (uncensored) observations < 100 to get an imputed value for the one that is left censored at 100.

Comment: @FrankHarrell under the case of random censoring, this will not work: for left censoring, E[Y | Y < 100 & Y is uncensored] > E[ Y | Y < 100 & Y is left censored] for continuous Y (and any discrete RV with multiple values less than 100). So your imputations will be biased. In the case of constant censoring, there simply won't be any values to use.

Comment: No, this has been verified to work in the case of right random censoring (the "redistribution to the right" method).  The purpose of the imputation is not to produce an unbiased observation.  It is to produce an entire sample to produce an unbiased summary statistic.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: hmm, I'll have to read up on this. It doesn't quite make sense to me but there's probably something I'm missing.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: after reading up, I learned this reproduces the KM curves...but those can have a *very* biased estimate of the mean. See my edits.

Comment: The mean is the area under the KM curve.  So if the estimate of the survival curve is unbiased the estimate of the mean also has to be unbiased.

Comment: Can you clarify — what is the distribution for which your simulation estimates the mean, what is the cutoff in the simulation, and is it a lower cutoff as in the question?

Comment: @FrankHarrell: But the KM curves *are* biased, as are integrals of the KM curves: see [here](http://www.ressources-actuarielles.net/EXT/ISFA/1226.nsf/0/9d659fb545364634c125749f002626da/$FILE/biasKM.pdf). This paper mentions that the bias is discussed in the original paper as well.

Comment: This bias is negligible.

Comment: @MattF: in my simulation, both the censoring time and event time are exp(1) distributed. It's right censored, not left. It's gotten off topic from the question, but it does show that a very large bias (ie 20% with a moderate sample size + moderately strong censoring) can be induced from using the KM curves to estimate the mean. Note that in the case with a constant cutoff, this approach fails much worse, since nothing is greater than the cutoff. .

Comment: The only bias of that magnitude should occur when you are not able to integrate the KM curve to $t=\infty$, i.e., when the most extreme observation is censored.

Comment: But that's exactly what right censoring (or left) does: the higher the value, the more likely it is to be censored! See my example, which I believe to be not uncommon data to come out of a clinical trial (i.e. n = 100, 50% censored). The resulting mean of the estimator of an exponential 1 is off by 20%, which is definitely more than "negligible": it would be unacceptable for any real analysis!

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what's going on here, especially since the data I'm dealing with are not survival data -- the specific case I'm interested in is analytical measurements with limits of detection. So there is not really a concept of time and I am getting confused at the step of applying a kaplan-meier estimate to the data. Can this still be reframed in terms of a survival problem?

Comment: @wzbillings: Kaplan Meier curves are a way of estimating the CDF (or survival = 1 -CDF) from right censored or left censored data. Doesn't actually need to be time-to-event, it's just most common for that application. But in your case, it is kind of overkill since your censoring is a constant limit of detection. As long as >50% of your sample is detected (i.e. not censored), you don't even to use the KM curves: simply replace your censored values with $U$ and compute the median. If you really have normal data, then the true mean should equal the median.

Comment: @CliffAB OK, I think I understand better now. The KM estimator uses the actual values along with an indicator for whether an observation is censored. So in place of the time-to-event, you can put any censored variable. The data is based on a simulation and for some parameter inputs, there are more than 50% censoring so I need to use the KM estimator for all of them to compare to the Bayesian estimator. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a consistent estimator based on method of moments. Suppose

\begin{align}
X &\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)\\
Y &=\max(U,X)\\
p &=P[Y>U]\\
q &=E[Y-U]\\
r &=E[(Y-U)Y]
\end{align}
where we estimate $p,q,r$ from averages of the data in the problem.

Those variables are defined by integrals, and the integrals lead to an equation which we can solve numerically for
$\mu$:
$$\sqrt{\frac{r-q\mu}{2\pi p}}\,\exp\left(\frac{-p(\mu-U)^2}{2(r-q\mu)}\right)=q-p(\mu-U).$$

This equation has the following interpretation: Let $s=\sqrt{(r-q\mu)/p}$, which is equal to $\sigma$ if we have the exact values for $\mu,p,q,r$. Let $Z\sim N(\mu,s)$. Then
$$f_Z(U) = \frac{q - p(\mu-U)}{s^2}.$$

**Example**: Suppose we use this procedure with 100 standard normal variables with a left cutoff at $u=1$. Simulating this 1000 times, I found estimated means that are only slightly biased, averaging around -0.006 with a standard deviation around 0.3. The accuracy is even better for lower cutoffs.

[image]

```
roots = c()
for(i in 1:100000){
  u = 1
  x = rnorm(100)
  y = pmax(x,u)
  p = mean(y>u)
  q = mean(y-u)
  r = mean((y-u)*y)
  
  f = function(mu){
    s2 = max(0,(r-q*mu)/p)
    ex = exp(-(u-mu)^2/(2*s2))
    return(sqrt(s2/(2*pi)) * ex - (q-p*(mu-u)))
  }
  
  if(f(-r/q)>0)
    root = r/q
  else
    root = uniroot(f, c(-r/q, r/q))$root
  roots = c(roots, root)
}
hist(roots)
c(mean(roots), sd(roots))
```

Comment: Nice analysis.  But I believe this estimator will be biased, though.

Comment: +1, this answer makes sense to me in the context of my problem. Before I do a direct comparison with the Bayesian method though, I'll have to try some simulations to see how much bias I get under different parameters. Thank you! I'll wait a bit longer before accepting to see if I can get some more explanation on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is maybe the simplest answer: If

\begin{align}
p &= P[X>U] \\
m &= \text{median}\{X:X>U\}\\
q_u &= \Phi^{-1}(1-p)\\
q_m &= \Phi^{-1}(1-p/2)\\
\end{align}
then $u=\mu+\sigma q_u$ and $m = \mu + \sigma q_m$ lead to the estimate of:
$$\mu \simeq \frac{uq_m-mq_u}{q_m-q_u}.$$
This does as well as my moments-based answer for $u<0$, is more volatile and more biased for $0<u<2$, and is more volatile but less biased for $u>2$.

Since this estimator is simple, maybe I or maybe someone else can figure out how to correct its bias.